# Subtract a date by 1 or 2 in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I need to get a date by subtracting a number from current date in MM/dd/yyyy format

I got the current date by using `new Date().format("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Please help me with a function that subtracts 1,2 to the above date and produces a date in MM/dd/yyyy format

I have tried

```
def today = new Date().format("MM/dd/yyyy")
def yesterday = today -1
println today
println yesterday
```

which gives me

```
01/11/2012
0/11/2012
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are subtracting from a String

try:

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today - 1
println today.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
println yesterday.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Oh! thanks, also how does it always chooses `dd` to subtract?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon As it says [in the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#minus%28int%29), it _"Subtract a number of days from this date and returns the new date."_

Answer (score 14):

Groovy comes with some really useful methods for manipulating dates you can use **.previous()** for the day before and **.next()** for the day after.

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today.previous()
println today.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
println yesterday.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

would you belive it if I said:    `MyDate - 2`  :)

Comment: This came to mind but my output was weird, see my updated question

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Because you've formatted it--it's not a `Date` any more. What does `format` return???