# Need to get list of dates previous date from current date

Tags: jmeter

I need to get list of previous dates from current date
For example today date is 9.7.2022 i need to get 10 dates like
8.9.2022
7.9.2022
6.9.2022
etc
I have tried with JSR223 sampler with some available code in the internet but not worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying and pasting code without understanding what it's doing is not the best way to proceed, however if you prefer:

```
1.upto(10, {
    log.info((new Date() - it).format('M.d.yyyy'))
})
```

[image]

More information:

- [Subtract a date by 1 or 2 in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816990/subtract-a-date-by-1-or-2-in-groovy)
- [Groovy: Add or Subtract Date Time Using TimeCategory](https://www.djamware.com/post/58cc05bb80aca72df8d1cf7d/groovy-add-or-subtract-date-time-using-timecategory)

Also be aware of JMeter's built-in [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timeshift-function)

[image]